# Looking for a Google Sheet Array Formula

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas

I'm looking for assistance in Google Sheet - array formula for column B (attached the similar in snippet). We can achieve it with a simple formula (on B2) with dragging option. Is there a way to achieve it in a better way without dragging the formulas manually.

[image: Google Sheet snippet]

Any help would be much Appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Delete everything from B2:B and place the following in B2:

`=ArrayFormula(IF(A2:A="",,VLOOKUP(TEXT(ROW(A2:A),"00000")&A2:A,{FILTER({TEXT(ROW(A2:A),"00000")&A2:A;""},{A2:A;""}<>"",{A2:A;""}<>A:A),SEQUENCE(COUNTA(FILTER(A2:A&ROW(A2:A),A2:A<>"",A2:A<>{A3:A;""})))},2,TRUE)))`

You'll notice throughout the formula ranges paired with a semicolon and empty set of quotes, all contained within curly brackets `{ }`. These allow us to form virtual ranges of equal length to compare with real ranges that run full-column.

`TEXT(ROW(A2:A),"00000")&A2:A` forms a concatenation of every row (in the format "00000" for uniformity of length) with the contents of Column A for `A2:A`. Then `FILTER` filters in only such concatenations where the content does not match what is in the row above. A second virtual column is formed by `SEQUENCE`, which uses `COUNTA` on a variation of the first `FILTER` to know how many items were filtered in.

`VLOOKUP` then looks up the `TEXT(ROW(A2:A),"00000")&A2:A` concatenation of *every* row in `A2:A` (not just the filtered ones) within the filtered list and returns the `SEQUENCE` number. Because the order of the rows in "00000" format will be in exact ascending order, we can use `TRUE` as the final parameter of `VLOOKUP`, which will drop back to the closest previous match if an exact match is not found, thus producing the same `SEQUENCE` numbers for duplicate content.

Answer (score 1):

I need a helper column for this:

**`B3`:**

```
=ArrayFormula(IF(A3:A10=A2:A9,0,1))
```

**`C3`:**

```
=ArrayFormula(SUMIF(ROW(A3:10),"<="&ROW(A3:A10),B3:B10)+B2)
```

---

If you want to skip the ending row number

**`B2`:**

```
=ArrayFormula({1;IF(A3:A="",,IF(A3:A=A2:A,0,1))})
```

**`C2`:**

```
=ArrayFormula(IF(B2:B="",,SUMIF(ROW(A2:A),"<="&ROW(A2:A),B2:B)))
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your prompt response.. Works fine.. But as it involves the additional helper column, I have used the other answer by Erik.. Thanks a lot again for looking into this..